# How to debug Office.js + Excel 2016 crashes

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js

(Rewrote this entire post. Please check edit history for previous version)

Help needed:

1. I am experiencing frequent Excel (desktop) crashes with my Office.js project
2. Crashes even with all Exception breakpoints enabled in VS
3. Seems to crash at random
4. Only an APPCRASH log in EventViewer
5. Code runs fine in Excel Online
6. Need advice on a better workflow (debugging crashes) for Office.js development.

My environment:

1. Typescript@2.3.2
2. core-js@2.4.1 (Promise polyfill)
3. Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3)
4. Excel 2016 Pro Plus - 1703 (Build 7967.2139)

I have finally reduced my code to a bare-minimum example.

1. Crashes at different iterations (ie, 1st, 6th, etc)
2. If I comment out either line (at `//TEST1` or `//TEST2`), then code runs till completion (must restart Excel completely after code change).

Code:

```
// Office.js entry point
Office.initialize = async function (reason) {

    console.log("Office.JS initialized!");
    console.log("Test Start");
    for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        console.log(`Iteration ${i}`);

        await ConvertToListObjectTest(); // TEST1
        await DeleteEntireRowTest();     // TEST2
    }
    console.log("Test End");

}

// Setup: Generates and activates a random, test worksheet
async function Setup(ctx: Excel.RequestContext): Promise<Excel.Worksheet> {

    // Create
    const sheetName = `Sheet${+new Date}`;
    const worksheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.add(sheetName);
    ctx.trackedObjects.add(worksheet);

    // Activate
    worksheet.activate();
    await ctx.sync();

    return worksheet;
}

// TearDown: Cleanup test worksheet
async function TearDown(ctx:Excel.RequestContext, worksheet: Excel.Worksheet): Promise<void> {
    worksheet.delete();
    await ctx.sync();
}

// Test deleting entire rows, given a range
async function DeleteEntireRowTest(): Promise<void> {

    await Excel.run( async ctx=> {
        // == SETUP ============
        const worksheet = await Setup(ctx);

        // == RUN ============
        // Range to delete
        const range = await worksheet.getRange("B1:B2");
        ctx.trackedObjects.add(range);
        await ctx.sync();

        // Get entire rows from range
        const entireRow = range.getEntireRow();
        entireRow.load("address");
        await ctx.sync();
        ctx.trackedObjects.add(entireRow);

        // Delete entire rows
        console.log(`Deleting: ${entireRow.address}`);
        entireRow.delete(Excel.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
        await ctx.sync();

        // == CLEAN UP ============
        await TearDown(ctx, worksheet);
    });
}

// Test: Given a range, convert to table
async function ConvertToListObjectTest(): Promise<void> {

    await Excel.run( async ctx => {
        // == SETUP ============
        const worksheet = await Setup(ctx);

        // == RUN ============

        // Ger range to convert
        const range = worksheet.getRange("B3:E20");
        ctx.trackedObjects.add(range);

        // Convert to table
        const table = worksheet.tables.add(range, true);
        ctx.trackedObjects.add(table);
        await ctx.sync();

        // Check table name
        table.load("name");
        await ctx.sync();
        console.log("Table added: " + table.name);

        // == CLEAN UP ============
        await TearDown(ctx, worksheet);
    });
}
```

Because there is no crash info, nor does it break in Visual Studio, I have no idea when/where/what is causing the crash.

In order to come up with this bare-minimum example, I literally had to comment my code line-by-line, recompile, rerun and crash, repeat.

This was an extremely painful process of isolating the offending code.

So my last question is:

**is there a better way/workflow for developing office.js projects**? Especially when dealing with bugs, whether it is my code, office.js, or Excel itself?

Comment: Let me ask around, and we'll get back to you.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Thanks. I've recently updated my question with code, if it'll help.